# PyQt4 Installation on Windows 10

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt4

Right when I start to install PyQt4, I'm getting an error message: “Error opening file for writing:” “C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\sip.pyd”.  The file does exist, and it is not read only.

I have 64 bit Windows 10 and 32 bit Python2.7, so I chose to install this file PyQt4-4.11.4-gpl-Py2.7-Qt4.8.7-x32.exe.

Before this, I did install SIP by running `python configure.py`, `make`, and then `make install` without errors.

How can I fix this error?  Is it safe to hit the ignore button?
[image: PyQt Error Message]

Comment: technically I didn't use make and make install.  I used nmake which I got by installing Visual Studio Community.

Comment: Have you tried running the installer with administrative privileges?

Comment: @three_pineapples Thanks for the suggestion, but I still get the same error message.

Comment: Well I'm not really familiar with compiling SIP (SIP and PyQt are included with the Python distro I use). My only other suggestion would be to make sure you compiled a 32-bit version of SIP

Comment: As explained on the download page, "these binary installers for Windows contain everything needed for PyQt4 development except for Python itself". So you do **not** need to compile and install sip if you use the binary packages. To fix your problem, remove whatever you have installed already, and then re-run the installer.